# Python Selenium print out value of textfield is showing empty. The value is not printing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to print out the value of a textfield to the console.
The webpage has the value 1,000.000 in the textfield.  1,000.000
should be printed but my method is printing blank.
I am using Python Webdriver.  I am using the .text which should get the text value of the textfield.

My method is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# max records textfield has the value 1,000.000 as default
def print_maxrecords_textfield(self):
    max_records_textfield = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel myinlineblock marginbelow" and contains(text(), "Max records")]/following-sibling::*'))
    print "max_records_textfield = "
    print max_records_textfield.text
```

I call the method from my test case class as dp.print_maxrecords_textfield()

The output to the console is as follows:

```
max_records_textfield =
```

It should say max_records_textfield = 1,000.00

The HTML snippet is:

```
<div class="padding gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="clear">
        <span class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" style="width: 8em;">Location</span>
        <input class="gwt-TextBox marginbelow" type="text" style="width: 30em;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <span class="gwt-InlineLabel myinlineblock marginbelow" style="width: 8em;">Max records</span>
        <input class="gwt-IntegerBox marginbelow" type="text"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually try getting the value instead of text.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# max records textfield has the value 1,000.000 as default
def print_maxrecords_textfield(self):
    max_records_textfield = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel myinlineblock marginbelow" and contains(text(), "Max records")]/following-sibling::*'))
    print "max_records_textfield = "
    print max_records_textfield.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: This works, I get the output max_records_textfield = 1,000,000  Thanks very much.  What does .text do then?

Comment: `get_attribute('value')` captures the attribute where the actual value is stored. On the other hand, text captures the innertext