# Selenium Python print out value of textfield using get_attribute('value') is not printing the value. I am getting blank printed

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print out the value of a textfield.  The value is not being printed out, i am getting a blank output, empty.  The textfield does have a value on the web page.
I am using name_element.get_attribute('value')  This should print the value of the textfield.  I do not know why it is not working for me.

In PyCharm the console output is:
print_value_from_name_textfield

The next line is not printing out the value  print name_element.get_attribute('value')

I am expecting the value "Data Object Name" to be printed as this is the value that is in the textfield on the web page.  I am getting a blank output.

My code snippet is:

```
def print_value_from_name_textfield(self):
    name_element = self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_Name_textfield_edit)
    print "print_value_from_name_textfield"
    print name_element.get_attribute('value')
```

The HTML is:

```
    <div class="marginbelow">
        <span class="gwt-InlineLabel defaultFormLabelWidthCompact myinlineblock">Name</span>
        <input id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tb_name" class="gwt-TextBox" type="text"/>
    </div>
```

In MainPageLocators the textfield id is defined as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class MainPageLocators(object):
    data_objects_Name_textfield_edit = (By.ID, 'data_configuration_edit_data_object_tb_name')
```

get_element implementation is:

```
# returns the element if found
def get_element(self, how, what):
    # params how: By locator type
    # params what: locator value
    try:
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print what
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        screenshot_name = how + what + get_datetime_now() # create screenshot name of the name of the element + locator + todays date time.  This way the screenshot name will be unique and be able to save
        self.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)
        raise
    return element
```

What am I doing wrong please?
Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: I don't see any attribute value in the input element, this is why it returns blank.

Comment: get_attribute('value') captures the attribute where the actual value is stored. text captures the innertext

Comment: I had asked a question a few months ago how to get the value printed from a textfield.  That html snippet did not have any attribute value in the input element.  The value got printed by using get_attribute('value').  My other question link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609234/python-selenium-print-out-value-of-textfield-is-showing-empty-the-value-is-not

Comment: Are you sure there is only one element with provided Id??

Comment: Yes am sure, thanks

Comment: What happened if you trying to find value at browser console as `document.getElementById("data_configuration_edit_data_object_tb_name").value`...?? Could you try it..??

Comment: I get the value "Data Object NAME" printed in the browser console.

Comment: Ok means problem solved.. one thing more tell me is this value in input available after some time??

Comment: Yes, the page could take a second or so to load when data objects link is clicked.  The value is then displayed when the page is loaded.  I will try putting a delay in there

Comment: Ok then implement `implicitly_wait` to for wait to load text on input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If unfortunately `get_attribute('value')` does not work, you can try using `execute_script()` to get input value as below :-

```
print self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].value",name_element)
```

**Edited**: If value in input field loaded after some time, you should implement some implicit wait before finding input element as below :

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

name_element = self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_Name_textfield_edit)
print "print_value_from_name_textfield"
print name_element.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: I have got the value of the textfield printed out to the console now.  Your method worked.  Thank you.  It is strange get_attribute('value') doesn't work for this element.  It works for my other elements.  Your alternative workaround ("return arguments[0].value",name_element) works.